# oracle job only running manually

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, schedule, sql-job

```
PROCEDURE CRIAR_JOB_LIMPA_proc IS
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name        => 'JOB_LIMPA_TAB',
    job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
    job_action      => 'SIIMA_JOB_LIMPA_TAB_pkg' || '.LIMPAR_TAB_proc',
    start_date      => To_Date('12-NOV-2018 11:20 AM', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi AM' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'),
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=minutely;interval=3',
     comments             => 'Inserir em tabela backup e apagar na original',
    enabled         => TRUE);
END;
```

I have this job, that runs well when i execute it manually, but it never starts whenever i set a start date, i have tried setting a timezone and everything but it does not seem to help.

Any ideas of possible issues/fixes?

Thank you

Comment: Apart from Wernfried's answer, putting that in a  procedure does not trigger  the job, it just compiles the procedure. Use an anonymous block or execute the procedure.

Answer (score 5):

`DATE` values do not support any time zone so `AT TIME ZONE ...` in combination with `TO_DATE` is useless. Try `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` or use TIMESTAMP literals, e.g. `start_date => TIMESTAMP '2019-11-12 11:20:00 UTC'` or try `start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP`

Your actual problem is the start_date, look carefully:

```
start_date => To_Date('12-NOV-2019 11:20 AM', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi AM' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT')
```

`12-NOV-2019` - today we have 12-NOV-**2018**, so your job will start running in one year.

Please ask the question again in one year if the job still hasn't started this time :-)

I am not sure, perhaps you have to add a semicolon and try `PLSQL_BLOCK` ratehr than `STORED_PROCEDURE`, i.e.

```
job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
job_action => 'SIIMA_JOB_LIMPA_TAB_pkg.LIMPAR_TAB_proc;'
```

Comment: i have 2018, its not working, so that was not the problem :)

Comment: but i will try your other suggestions :P

Comment: @Sapo121, try to add a semicolon at the job_action.

Comment: ill try, but if that was the problem it should not work when running it manually

Comment: Right, then I assume the problem must be related to `start_date`

Comment: `SYSDATE` is also a `DATE` data type. Try `SYSTIMESTAMP`

Comment: thanks for your help, it seems the problem has to do with database privileges.